# Keyboard shortcut to evaluate notebook

Tags: front-end, evaluation, notebooks, customization, keyboard

(If this is entirely trivial, although I couldn't find an answer as much as I searched the archives, I will delete the question.)

How could I add a keyboard shortcut to evaluate the entire notebook instead of going to `Evaluation -> Evaluate Notebook` again and again ?

Comment: I would post in answer, but I haven't tried it. Check out [customizing Mathematica shortcuts] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts) with the token EvaluateNotebook similar to the EvaluatorQuit demonstrated

Comment: Thanks; I added it (`EvaluateNotebook`), but it enters an infinite loop. Also there are a couple of links in answer, that are no longer available.

Comment: How about Command-A followed by enter?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Personally I would use what bill_s suggested, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But if you want to have one shortcut you can use what Timothy linked. Just add this line to the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file:

```
 Item[KeyEvent["h", Modifiers -> {Control}], 
      FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[ ], "EvaluateNotebook"]]]
```

it works for me.

---

Your infinite loop probably showed while testing on the notebook. Well, if you want to evaluate notebook and the last line is

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluateNotebook"]
```

then it will definitelly result in such loop.

Comment: does this shortcut still work? I can't get Mathematica 10 to recognize it (it just makes a *ding* sound when I try to execute it)

Comment: @Hanmyo ctrl+h? Have you edited KeyEventTranslations.tr? I will try later but I think it should work.

Comment: Yep, I put the line in that file and it didn't work for me. I think maybe it recognized that the command was in the file but maybe the command didn't work? I'm just guessing here, but it does make a ding noise when I hit ctrl+h, it just doesn't evaluate the notebook or do anything else.

Answer (score 13):

For OSX you can do the following.

1. Select Mathematica.
2. Click on "Mathematica" menu then "Services -> Services Preferences..."
3. Select "Shortcuts" tab.
4. In the left side select "App Shortcuts".
5. Click the + button.
6. Fill out the following.

   [image]
7. Click add after you have set your short cut key and you are good to go.

Comment: Wow, that is really easy, thanks!

Comment: How may I use Simon O'Doherty method for commands that are nested in a menu, e.g., Evaluation -> Quit Kernel -> Local? Adding 'Local' or 'Quit Kernel -> Local' in 'Menu Title' does not work.

Comment: @James Please do not use answers as a followup questions. If your comment won't get answered you can ask a separate question.

Answer (score 8):

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then <kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>o</kbd> (they don't have to be entered at the same time, just in succession). That's the same as Evaluation > Evaluate Notebook

Comment: +1 note the "evaluate notebook" menu item was curiously missing in some versions, glad to see it back.

Comment: In what versions does this work? It seems that here it doesn't (Mac OSX, Mathematica 9.0.1). Thanks!

Comment: I use Windows 7 and MMA 9. Have you tried it with the Command/Control/Option key? Also, you don't have to hit all the keys at once; I usually hit "Alt" *lift finger* "v" *lift finger* "o".

Comment: (+1) How did you know this? I couldn't find it in the documentation! :)

Comment: works for me on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

1. Goto `C:\.....\Mathematica\System Files\Front End\TextResources\Windows`
2. Open the file: `KeyEventTranslations.tr`
3. Locate line 11 of this file:

   ```
   Item[KeyEvent["KeypadEnter", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "EvaluateNextCell"],
   ```
4. Change this line to:

   ```
   Item[KeyEvent["KeypadEnter", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "EvaluateNoteBook"],
   ```
5. Save and restart Mathematica.

After making this change pressing the key combination <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>KeypadEnter</kbd> will cause Mathematica to evaluate the notebook.

Comment: The last suggestion works (user65421) perfectly except the 'b' in "EvaluateNoteBook" must be lowercase--at least in version 13.