# How can I copy & paste cell styles?

Tags: front-end, cells

In Mac's mail app the key shortcut "command + option + c" gives a copy selected text style and "cmd + opt + v" pastes the style. Is there a way to achieve this with cell styles? The keyboard part is solved in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33197/keyboard-shortcut-to-evaluate-notebook), I'm just not sure how to effect the "copy-style" part of this problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cell styles?  Are you referring to the Stylesheet types accessed in the **Format** > **Style** menu, or to formatting applied at the Cell level (font size, background color, etc.)?

Comment: Both or either would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved my goal with this code in MenuSetup.tr. Here is copy-cell-style:

```
MenuItem["Copy Cell Style",
        FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], All,         FrontEnd`EvaluationCell],
            KernelExecute[
                $mystyle = FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookRead[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[]]];
     $mystyle = $mystyle[[2]];
            ]
        }],
      MenuKey["c", Modifiers -> {"Command", "Shift"}], MenuEvaluator -> "Local"]
```

and paste-cell-style:

```
MenuItem["Paste Cell Style",
            FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], All, FrontEnd`EvaluationCell],
 KernelExecute[
 $mycell = FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookRead[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[]]];
    $mycell = $mycell[[1]];FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[],Cell[$mycell,$mystyle]]];
                ]
            }],
          MenuKey["v", Modifiers -> {"Command", "Shift"}], MenuEvaluator -> "Local"]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In conclusion, we can only use `System` calls like `Set[]` friends inside `KernelExecute`, and we can only use `Frontend` calls inside `FrontEndExecute`, and these might have to be wrapped inside each-other depending on context...

Comment: Does no-one find this useful?

Comment: @anyone hmmmmm?

Comment: For what it's worth I find it useful and you have my vote on both question and answer.