# How to programmatically Evaluate Notebook (all cells in an open notebook) rather than from Evaluation menu?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, notebooks, customization, user-interface

I am working on a `DockedCells` toolbar for common tasks like `Save`, `ClearAll`, scrolling, etc., etc. My next addition to that toolbar is creating a button that executes `Evaluation -> Evaluate Notebook`. I only need the function to work. I already know how to insert that into a button.

When I type `NotebookEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[], InsertResults -> True]`directly into a cell and doing a `Shift-Enter` nothing visual happens other than showing `(Running...)` for an extended period of time at the top window frame of the notebook. I am not sure what is supposed to happen here so I did an `Abort Evaluation` as too much time has passed. It should only take 1 second for this particular notebook.

Why isn't this behaving like doing `Evaluation -> Evaluate Notebook` from the menu?

Comment: If you run this it will run itself over and over, won't it? Related: [33197](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33197/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to what Kuba said: you can avoid the infinite loop by creating a button that starts the evaluation:

```
Button["Evaluate notebook",
 NotebookEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[], InsertResults -> True],
 Method -> "Queued"
]
```

Note the `Method` option. Without it, the FE will freeze up completely.

Comment: Sjoerd-Smit it works!!! thank you so much. i had been struggling with this flocking thing all day.